# Why $\mathbb E[X_T\boldsymbol 1_{(\sup_n X_n\geq \lambda }]\geq \lambda \mathbb P(\sup_n X_n\geq \lambda )$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_n)$ a martingale indexed by a finite set $(0,...,N)$ (but the fact that it's a martingale is not important for my question). Let $T=\inf\{n\mid X_n\geq \lambda \}$ if this set is not empty en $T=N$ otherwise.

Then $$\mathbb E[X_T\boldsymbol 1_{(\sup_n X_n\geq \lambda )}]\geq \lambda \mathbb P(\sup_n X_n\geq \lambda ),$$
because $X_T\geq \lambda $ on $(\sup_n X_n\geq \lambda )$.

---

**Question :** I agree if $\{n\mid X_n\geq \lambda \}\neq \emptyset$, but if it's the empty set it's not true, no ? Because $X_T\geq \lambda $ won't be true anymore since $N\notin\{n\mid X_n\geq \lambda \}$. I really have truble to understand this point.

This proof comes from the proof of proposition 1.5 page 53 of the third edition of *continuous martingales and Brownian motion* of Yor and Revus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a step back.
$$X_{T}I_{(\sup_{n}X_{n}\geq\lambda)} \ge \lambda I_{(\sup_{n}X_{n}\geq\lambda)}$$

Take Expectation on both sides, and you get your inequality.

Comment: I completely agree if $\inf\{n\mid X_n\geq \lambda \}$. Nevertheless if the set is the emptyset, then $T=N$. And since $N\notin \{n\mid X_n\geq \lambda \}$ I do not agree that $X_T\geq \lambda$. You know what I mean ?

Comment: True. But what you need to keep in mind is that $X_{T}$ is a random variable. A function from the sample space to the real line. Sometimes it is bigger than $\lambda$. Sometimes it's not. What Expectation does, is it describes a general property of the random variable. So the random variable $X_{T}I_{(sup_{n}X_{n}\geq\lambda)}$ has expected value greater than RHS.

Answer (score 2):

On $(\sup_n X_n\geq \lambda),$ you, by definition, have that $\{n|X_n\geq \lambda\}\neq \emptyset,$ since your indexing set is finite, so really, $\sup_n X_n=\max_n X_n$.

Comment: I don't understand, if so, why do we consider $T=N$ if $\{n\mid X_n\geq \lambda \}$ ? You think that this will never be true ?

Comment: What will never be true?

Comment: You pick an event $\omega\in (\sup_n X_n\geq \lambda)$. Then, there is some $k(\omega)$ such that $X_{k(\omega)}(\omega)=\sup_n X_n(\omega)\geq \lambda$. Then $k(\omega)\in \{n| X_n(\omega)\geq \lambda\},$ so the set is non-empty.

Comment: Suppose $(\sup_n X_n\geq \lambda )=\emptyset$. Then $X_T=X_N<\lambda $, then $X_T\geq \lambda $ won't be true, and thus, $\mathbb E[X_T\boldsymbol 1_{(\sup_n X_n)}]\geq \lambda \mathbb P(\sup_n X_n)$ won't be true as well... no ?

Comment: If $(\sup_n X_n\geq \lambda)=\emptyset,$ then it has probability $0$, and your inequality works just fine.

Comment: I think you are somewhat confused about the fact that $\{n|X_n\geq \lambda\}$ is a random set of integers.